# AWS IOT - Credential should be scoped to correct service

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, iot, aws-iot

I am trying to access a simple AWS IOT REST service but I have not been able to do so successfully yet. Here is what I did.

1. I created an iam user in my aws and downloaded the access key and secret key
2. Logged into AWS IOT with that user and created a "thing"
3. From the thing's property I found the REST URL for the shadow
4. Used Postman with the new "aws signature" feature and provided it with the access key, secret key, region (us-east-1) and service name (iot)
5. Tried to "GET" the endpoint and this is what I got -

   `{
         "message": "Credential should be scoped to correct service. ",
         "traceId": "be056198-d202-455f-ab85-805defd1260d"
   }`
6. I thought there is something wrong with postman so I tried using aws-sdk-sample example of connecting to S3 and changed it to connect to the IOT URL. 
   Here is my program snippet (Java)

   ```
   String awsAccessKey = "fasfasfasdfsdafs";
   String awsSecretKey = "asdfasdfasfasdfasdfasdf/asdfsdafsd/fsdafasdf";

   URL  endpointUrl = null;
   String regionName = "us-east-1";
   try {
       endpointUrl = new URL("https://dasfsdfasdf.iot.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/things/SOMETHING/shadow");
   }catch (Exception e){
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
   Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
   headers.put("x-amz-content-sha256", AWSSignerBase.EMPTY_BODY_SHA256);

   AWSSignerForAuthorizationHeader signer = new AWSSignerForAuthorizationHeader(
           endpointUrl, "GET", "iot", regionName);
   String authorization = signer.computeSignature(headers,
           null, // no query parameters
           AWSSignerBase.EMPTY_BODY_SHA256,
           awsAccessKey,
           awsSecretKey);

   // place the computed signature into a formatted 'Authorization' header
   // and call S3
   headers.put("Authorization", authorization);
   String response = HttpUtils.invokeHttpRequest(endpointUrl, "GET", headers, null);
   System.out.println("--------- Response content ---------");
   System.out.println(response);
   System.out.println("------------------------------------");
   ```

This gives me the same error -

```
--------- Request headers ---------
x-amz-content-sha256: e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855
Authorization: AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=fasfasfasdfsdafs/20160212/us-east-1/iot/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=host;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date, Signature=3b2194051a8dde8fe617219c78c2a79b77ec92338028e9e917a74e8307f4e914
x-amz-date: 20160212T182525Z
Host: dasfsdfasdf.iot.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
--------- Response content ---------
{"message":"Credential should be scoped to correct service. ","traceId":"cd3e0d96-82fa-4da5-a4e1-b736af6c5e34"}
------------------------------------
```

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong please? AWS documentation does not have much information on this error. Please help

Comment: didi you solve the problem? I'm with the same

Comment: same problem here

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Sign your request with `iotdata` instead if `iot`
example:

```
AWSSignerForAuthorizationHeader signer = new AWSSignerForAuthorizationHeader(
    endpointUrl, "GET", "iotdata", regionName);
```

Comment: Was stuck trying to do this through Postman. This little bit about 'iotdata' is not found anywhere in api docs - thank you.

Comment: AWS has the absolute worst docs I've ever used. It took 3 days and lots of trial and error before I finally found this small detail that fixed my problem

Answer (score 3):

In your 4th step, don't fill anything for Service Name. Postman will default the value with execute-api.

Hope this works!

Answer (score 0):

Its basically due to Service name is not given correctly you can use service Name = 'iotdata' instead of iot.

If you user Key management then Service Name would be kms. 
For EC2 Service Name would be ec2 etc.

Answer (score -3):

Use the AWS IoT [SDK for Node.js](https://github.com/aws/aws-iot-device-sdk-js) instead. Download the IoT Console generated private key and client cert as well as the CA Root cert from [here](https://www.symantec.com/content/en/us/enterprise/verisign/roots/VeriSign-Class%203-Public-Primary-Certification-Authority-G5.pem). Start with the scripts in the examples directory.

Comment: That really doesn't answer the question that was asked.